# Wpf Math Boundary Logic

Tags: math, user-interface, geometry

I need some enlightenment on what might be a simple question.

Given a circle of coordinates *Xn* and *Yn*  that act as boundary and given the coordinate of a control's center at *X1* and *Y1*. How do I check if the control lies within the boundary?

I tried,

> X2 & X3 = the left & right peak of the circle in term of X axis.
>   Y2 & Y3 = the top & bottom peak of the circle in term of Y axis.

```
If( X1 > X2 && X1 < X3 && Y1 > Y2 && Y1 < Y3)
   return true;
```

However, this clearly doesn't work as the four corner of the circle will return true when it's not suppose to. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain what ** coordinates Xn and Yn that act as boundary** means?

Comment: Picture a circle being drawn by 360points, and I have all the 360points' coordinates. So I want the circle to act ad boundary so my control, let say a image, will always stay inside the circle and cannot exit it. That's what I'm trying to mean.

Comment: What does this have to do with [WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wpf/info)?

Comment: What does "four corner of the circle" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use something like r = sqrt(xn*xn + yn*yn) to determine the radius of the circle?  Even easier would be r = xn when yn = 0.  Then you can calculate r1 = sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1) to find out if r1 < r.  If it is, then it's inside the circle.

Comment: How does determine the radius of the circle and control help to make sure the control is inside the circle?

Comment: You have an outer limit of the circle defined by (xn,yn).  If your point (x1,y1) is outside that radius, then the control is not within the circle.  This assumes that the center of the circle and the center of the control are the same.  Or I could be totally off-base.

Comment: Nope. :(
The center of the control is different and it would change dynamically. So what I'm doing is moving the control around and would like the control to move only inside the circle. (:

Comment: @Sydnal, so just translate the control's center to the circles center.  It's just a little more math.